# DrayTek Vigor 2920(n): VPN with VLAN restrictions?

Tags: networking, routing, virtualization, vpn, local-area-network

I'm currently installing a DrayTek Vigor 2920n router in a new office. This router is to be used for 2 seperate companies. For one of these companies, the router has a LAN-2-LAN (VPN) connection to a datacenter configured. The other company should not be able to access this other (VPN-)network. I'm aware of the capability of this router to have VLAN's, but I cannot figure out how to configure the VPN-connection to only be accessible for VLAN0 and not for VLAN1.
I know I can also add another router to physically split both networks, but we bought the DrayTek with the idea that it could easily have the VPN-connection available for VLAN0 and not for VLAN1.
VLAN1 can easily be in another subnet, that's fine, although, I don't know how to configure that on this DrayTek.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

Comment: haha! I must still be sleepy (it's early) I was reading "StarTrek Voyager 2920" :) ... stupid dyslexia!

Comment: :D nah that's something else...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the LAN to LAN tunnels using differing IP addresses as you note, and as long as you do not add a route between the subnets they will not be able to communicate. Under your dial in settings, disable RIP, and do not add a static route.

The user guide section 4.96 gives a good start.

You cannot, add a WAN port to a VLAN using the GUI. However, you can set up your VLANs internally and then add port redirection from the WAN ports to forward to your VLAN'ed ports. This will ensure that the connections on your LAN to LAN profiles stay internal to the expected subnets. This is in section 4.3.1

Look at the sections I noted above in this document:

http://www.draytek.co.uk/support/userguides/Vigor2920%20User%20Guide%20V1.01.zip